# Why is unshift() returning a different value than push() if I am targeting the first element in the former and the last element in the latter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function for Project Euler #7. Towards the end, I changed the code from `primeArray.push(i);` to `primeArray.unshift(i)` and `return primeArray[primeArray.length - 1];` to `return primeArray[0];`. This altered the return. In the former. It returned the correct answer, 104021, while the latter returned 20001, which is not even prime. I do not understand why that is.

```js
function primeFinder(primeTarget) {
  //since 2 is the only even prime, putting it here saves us some effort in checking primality by just iterating over the odd numbers
  //it also helps the for loop since we are only interested in checking for divisors among previous primes.
  let primeArray = [2];
  let i = 3;

  while (primeArray.length < primeTarget) {
    let primeLogger = false;
    //We don't need to check for divisibility by 2, so j can equal 1
    for (j = 1; j < primeArray.length && primeArray[j] < Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
      if (i % primeArray[j] === 0) {
        primeLogger = true;
        //Since we have found a divisor and changed primeLogger, we can exit the loop
        break;
      }
    }
    //Where the break goes to, and also where the for loop goes to once finishes
    if (primeLogger === false) {
      primeArray.push(i);
    }
    i += 2;
  }
  return primeArray[primeArray.length - 1];
}
console.log(primeFinder(10001));
```

Comment: Off topic: [MDN - Using continue with a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#using_continue_with_a_label)

Answer (score 2):

Because `primeArray` is now in descending order but your loop still searches from start to end; now from biggest towards smaller values. Until it finds something that is `>= Math.sqrt(i)` which most likely will be the very first check, `j=1`.
Then it ends the loop with `primeLogger === false`

so for example, for:

```
i=9, j=1
primeArray === [7,5,3,2]
primeArray[j] === 5
```

And since the check `5 < Math.sqrt(9)` is `false` the loop is finished.

Therefore `9` is a prime number and is now added to the start of `primeArray`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; stupid of me to miss that.